# c# named iterators and yield

Tags: c#, yield

I've found this example which returns custom type Car objects in reverse order.
Can someone explain me this code. thanks

```
public IEnumerable GetTheCars(bool returnReversed)
{
   if(returnReversed)
   {
     for(int i=cars.Length; i!=0; i--)
     {
        yield return cars[i-1]; //this line makes me confused
     }
   }
   else {...}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is it that confuses you?

Comment: Do you need an explanation about `yield` or about how the cars are being returned in reverse order?

Comment: @davenewza how cars are being returned in reverse.

Comment: What don't you understand about that? Do you  understand the `for` loop?

Comment: You can look into [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx), [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx) and the [square bracket operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx) for more understanding about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indicated in your comments that you need an explanation of how the reverse ordering works.

```
   for(int i=cars.Length; i!=0; i--)
   {
        yield return cars[i-1]; //this line makes me confused
   }
```

Let's say you have 4 cars in your list.

Your `for` loop starts at a value of `cars.Length`, which will be 4.  For each iteration it decrements by 1.  It will continue doing this while the `i!=0` condition is met.  So, the loop will iterate with the following values of `i`: 4, 3, 2, 1.

If `i` is used as the element index for your array/list, then you will receive cars[4], cars[3], cars[2], cars[1] (reverse order!).  But because arrays in C# start at 0 (and not 1), you need to subtract 1 when accessing the elements: `cars[i-1]`.

Comment: altough my question was a bit confused this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

First the `yield` statement: When using `yield` you are returning a collection but the instead of defining a collection, putting all the items in it and then returning it, you yield return it, meaning that you code returns 1 items at the time and the runtime will keep track of all your yield returns, make a collections out of it and have the method return that.

For example:

```
public IEnumable GetInts
{
    get
    {
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
        yield return 4;
    }
}
```

and

```
public IEnumable GetInts
{
    get
    {
        var arr = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
        return arr;
    }
}
```

those are 2 codes that do the same. But when working in loops it can sometimes be more handy to work with yield than keep track of your collection yourself.

Comment: Just clarifying. The two code examples *do not* do the same. Your first paragraph explains the differences, and there's a big difference in how the code actually works.

Comment: They both return the a collection with the same content. There are indeed diferences but for the point at hand that doesn't matter (I thought)

Comment: The main difference is that with the yield, execution is lazy in the sense that the code will not execute until MoveNext is called on the IEnumerable that is returned. This is not the case when returning an array, where the collection is created there and then, and returned in whole. Therefore the statement "they do the same" is incorrect. But I'm sure you know this, I'm just pointing it out for readers that may not understand the difference yet.